# Wrap each child and it's grandchildren separately

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help separating the child pages, this is what I have right now:

```
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item page-item-54 page_item_has_children"><span>Title of Child1</span>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-60"><a>Grandchild1</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-62"><a>Grandchild2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-58 page_item_has_children"><span>Title of Child2</span>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-64"><a>Grandchild1</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-66"><a>Grandchild2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

and this is what I want to achieve:
[image]

```
<div class="children-list">
    <ul class="children">
        <span>Title of Child1</span>
        <li class="page_item page-item-60"><a>Grandchild1</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-62"><a>Grandchild2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="children">
        <span>Title of Child2</span>
        <li class="page_item page-item-64"><a>Grandchild1</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-66"><a>Grandchild2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the walker I'm using for wp_list_pages

```
class series_walker extends Walker_Page {
    public function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_page = 0 ) {
        if ( isset( $args['item_spacing'] ) && 'preserve' === $args['item_spacing'] ) {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        } else {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        }
        if ( $depth ) {
            $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
        } else {
            $indent = '';
        }

        $css_class = array( 'page_item', 'page-item-' . $page->ID );

        if ( isset( $args['pages_with_children'][ $page->ID ] ) ) {
            $css_class[] = 'page_item_has_children';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $current_page ) ) {
            $_current_page = get_post( $current_page );
            if ( $_current_page && in_array( $page->ID, $_current_page->ancestors ) ) {
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
            }
            if ( $page->ID == $current_page ) {
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
            } elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent ) {
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
            }
        } elseif ( $page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
        }

        $css_classes = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );

        if ( '' === $page->post_title ) {
            /* translators: %d: ID of a post */
            $page->post_title = sprintf( __( '#%d (no title)' ), $page->ID );
        }

        $args['link_before'] = empty( $args['link_before'] ) ? '' : $args['link_before'];
        $args['link_after'] = empty( $args['link_after'] ) ? '' : $args['link_after'];

        $atts = array();
        $atts['href'] = get_permalink( $page->ID );

        $output .= $indent . sprintf(
            '<li class="%s">'.(($depth == 1) ? '<span%s>%s%s%s</span>' : '<a%s>%s%s%s</a>'),
            $css_classes,
            $attributes,
            $args['link_before'],
            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ),
            $args['link_after']
        );
    }

}
```

I'm completely stuck. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Where to add the markup? What to modify?

Comment: The thing you want to acheive is not valid HTML markup since only `li` elements are allowed as direct children of `ul` or `ol`, anyway if you don't care about that and you're ok with using javascript to change the markup i can help you, messing with `walkers` is kinda nasty and sometimes you don't achieve what you want

Comment: Validation is not an issue, I'd rather have that setup than validating html. If there is a valid setup that could let separate the lists, I'm happy to use it. Thank you very much! I've added an image to the original post if that helps.

Comment: Don't know php solution, too, it seems easier with js(jQuery): https://jsfiddle.net/q97w4v7j/1/ :)

Comment: my answer would be the same as @sinisake's , jquery is quite handy in changing markups

Comment: Great news, I'm pretty sure you need to override more of the default functions, so you can dive into it deeper! You need to clear the `</li>` from `->end_el` and put it somewhere else. And then you still need to do more. But, looking at your included image this can just be styled with the original markup. And another option, you can just get the menu items without the walker and walk it the way your prefer.